# Unexplained Azure webapp memory consumption

Tags: asp.net-web-api, memory-management, memory-leaks, azure-web-app-service, out-of-memory

I am debugging unexplained memory consumption on one of our Azure Web apps. I spent many hours digging through logs , memory dumps using dotmemory, perfview, diagnostic tools but still unable to figure out why our app memory is increasing steadily through out the day.

One of the memory dump I downloaded was approx 900 MB but dotmemory shows only 26 MB for largest size objects [image]

I also performed countless diagnostic sessions with VS diagnostic tools and checked that app is releasing the resources at the end of every request [image]

Below is private bytes consumption at the beginning and end of the day
[image]

I verified multiple times in the heap to make sure the application objects / modules before and after request were being released and the above screenshot shows that it does .

I would if you could share any pointers on how to find what is consuming memory

Answer (score 0):

After spending good number of hours on researching, we found that the static variables in one of our libraries were holding on to the memory and never being released. We did spot those static variables in the visual memory snapshots but refused to believe that those were the actual cause of the issue and were trying to find the non existent objects.

we replaced the static variables with properties and that resolved the memory leak issue